# Issue with pmap not giving values in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am using pmap to get the memory usage of an application in a script. If I run the script myself I get a table detailing how much memory my app is using. 
I have a monitor app that is running a standard user and executes the script every now and then, it keeps getting 0 from the pmap command

```
pid_val=`pgrep $app_name`
mem_val=`pmap $pid_value`
```

Instead of returning columns of data I get

```
<pid>: <process name>
total    0k,
```

I'm using pmap so I can strip out the total memory at the end. An alternative command is also a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the value I wanted using the following

```
ps aux | grep <pid> | awk '{ print $5 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not executing this as root, you can't get info on memory of non-yours processes.